# Slick 3.0.0 (RC3) Hook "onCreate"

Tags: scala, playframework, hook, slick

I'm currently evaluating porting an application written in PHP (Laravel) to the Playframework and Slick (3.0).

One thing I really liked about working with Laravel was the fact that there were some "hooks" you could use, like "onCreate". 
What I mean by that is, that upon creation of a new "ModelA" I'd like to create multiple "ModelB"-rows based on that A, so I'd like to hook right into the creation-process of A and define how (many) B's should be created and how they should look.

Think of a node and a tree where for each node I want to add some paths to the nodetree.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to use your own abstraction layer.